# How to link PostgreSQL database to Django 1.9? Windows

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I've been looking for a lot of reference about installing the PostgreSQL database on Django. I've seen various answers but can't find the appropiate for me and mi OS.

Just downloaded PostgreSQL, and the **pg_config**. I just can't link it to Django to start working with the Database. When I try to run the server it appears a huge command finishing with:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-xnske745\psycopg2
```

I don't know where to find that 'setup.py' to execute it, nor how to configure the PATH for the database to detect de pg_config and to start running to database. My settings.py database look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
'NAME': 'database1',                      
'USER': 'root',
'PASSWORD': '123456',
'HOST': 'localhost',
'PORT': '8000',
}
}
```

So, what's wrong? How could I configure the PATH to make PostgreSQL work properly? I'm running Python 3.5, Django 1.9.1 and PostgreSQL 9.5. Already have in PostgreSQL directory the psycopg2-2.6.2.tar file.

Help would be really appreciate. Thank you!!

Comment: The psycopg2 [installation docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-a-package) suggest that Windows users install [this port](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

Comment: This one also works well with Windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unfortunately, I don't have that 'virtual enviroment' directory, and I can't execute the setuptools (I don't know how). What should I do in order to install the package and make the database work?? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I'm getting a bit crazy on this topic... I downloaded the port but I don't know what to do know cause I don't have that 'virtualenv' directory. Also I'm trying to install it a lot of ways with the cmd.exe and there always give me some kind of error.

Comment: I don't also know how to proceed once I downloaded the compiled library on lfd.uci.edu... Is there any way to use PostgreSQL with Django??